# Writing a code in Netlogo for summatory

Tags: sum, procedure, netlogo, equation

I am trying to write a code in Netlogo with which it can apply the next equation:

[image]

The equation represent the change of Se value (the number of a breed of turtles), the constant *kse* is a parameter value defined by a slider, the *next* value is another parameter defined by a slider and the summatory part, is the sum of the operation of the parentesis which is: each sj (that is a turtle-own variable) less the total of the breed population (Se)
The problem is with the summatory part because i really dont know how to write it. I though, made an ask procedure defining each variable with the "let" command but it give me wrong results, so i am thinking doing it with a report procedure but i really dont know how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Supposes the breed is `esses` and the turtle attribute is `s`, then

```
let _Se count esses
let _sum [s - _Se] of esses
```

Note: if this is really meant to govern the change in the number of turtles (as you indicate in your question), you will have to decide what to do with non-integer outcomes.